# CS1061 error when I try to connect two scripts in C# in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and C# and recently I got stuck on an error which I constantly receive without knowing the exaxt cause.

I am trying to connect a text script to my player script but it keeps saying that it can't acces the variable 'playerScore' even though I am connecting the player script to my text script.

here's the code of the text script:

```
public GameObject player;
public Text scoreText;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    scoreText.text = player.playerScore.ToString();
}
```

}

Comment: `player` is of type `GameObject`, which [doesn't seem to have a `playerScore` property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html).  Can you clarify where that property is defined?

Answer (score 1):

You can access variables or methods from other scripts by retrieving the script as a [component](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponent.html).

```
scoreText.text = player.GetComponent<OtherScript>().playerScore.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks man, it finally worked!